# how to get book_title written by author_name in for loop

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-queryset, manytomanyfield

how to get book name which is related author,
i want author name in first column and book name in 2nd column,
by querying Author.objects.all() i got author name but i want book name which is related to that author in 2nd column like.

col-1,      author-mahesh,      book-Harry potter
col-2,      author-naresh,      book-game of thrones

**models.py**

```
class Author(models.Model):
    author_name = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
    

    def __str__(self):
        return self.author_name
  
class Book(models.Model): 
    book_title = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
    desc = models.TextField(max_length = 300)
    authors = models.ManyToManyField(Author, related_name ='author')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.book_title

    def written_by(self):
        return   ",".join([str(p) for p in self.authors.all() ])
```

**views.py**

```
from .models import Author, Book
# Create your views here.
def manytomany(request):
    authors = Author.objects.all()
    book = Book.objects.all()
    
    # author_first = Author.objects.get(author_name='Mahesh')
    # book_author = author_first.author.all()
    
    book_author = Author.objects.get(id=1).author.all()
    context = {
        'authors':authors, 
        'book': book, 
        'book_author':book_author,
       
    }
    return render(request, 'many-to-many.html', context)
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="col-lg-12">
                <table  class="table table-striped">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Author Name</th>
                            <th>Book</th>
                        </tr>                       
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        {% for author in authors %}
                        <tr>               
                            <td>{{ author.author_name }}</td>                           
                            {% for j in book_author %}
                            <td>{{ j }}</td>
                            {% endfor %}
                        </tr>
                        {% endfor %}
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
```

Comment: `{% for j in author.author.all %}`...